# As soon as I add "perspective: 1px" the position of navbar is no longer fixed. How can I fix that?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I add the line "perspective: 1px" to my css file, the navbar is no longer fixed on top and starts scrolling. Why is that and how can I fixed that? Note that I need perspective for parallax effect and it cannot be omitted.

I am sure it's because of the perspective, because when I remove this line the navbar is fixed.

Here are my codes:

```css
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

main {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0; // remove the gap so it doesn't close
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100vh;
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parallax-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 20vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax-wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 300px;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("1.JPG");
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(6);
}

.regular-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 20vh;
  background-image: url("2.JPG");
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>

      <!-- Dropdown -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="parallax-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. .... .... Donec in justo eu ligula semper consequat sed a risus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="regular-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. .... .... Donec in justo eu ligula semper consequat sed a risus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you mistake with the class `fixed-top`& `sticky-top`?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks, sticky-top works. But fixed-top should also have worked. Shouldn't it?

Comment: read the duplicate until the end to understand what is happening. You need to consider anothe wrapper for your perspective where the position:fixed element isn't there